# Masking in Metal iOS

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I did masking like this in opengl as follows

```
vec4 patCol = texture2D(pattern, samplePos);
vec4 maskCol = texture2D(tex0, texCoordVarying);
gl_FragColor=vec4(patCol.xyz, patCol.w);
```

I want to do the same masking in iOS the texture in maskCol is Semi Transparent. When I couldn't get the similar output in Metal. Can any body help me in this.

Renderpipeline Descriptor

```
let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = 1
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the alpha channel of your mask texture is loading correctly? Can you share your render pipeline configuration, particularly the properties related to blending?

Comment: What is this code meant to do? It looks like you are just loading patCol and then assigning that to the alpha channel. Thing is colors need to be pre-multipled, you need to grab the alpha channel value and multiply it by the xyz for the RGB data.

Comment: That feels like a typo to me. It seems like the intention was to use `maskCol.w` as the alpha value of the returned color. Whether or not the RGB values should be multiplied through by the alpha value depends somewhat on the blending configuration.

Comment: Well, it could be the case that the xyz part (the RGB data) is already pre-multiplied. Original poster will have to explain a little more about what logic is actually intended and how the Metal implementation is not doing what is expected.

Comment: Image data [should in general be stored pre-multiplied](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/gpus-prefer-premultiplication/), but when using an image mask, the source image is often opaque. If the source image isn't actually opaque, ignoring the alpha of the source image (rather than modulating it with the mask) is equivalent to matting it against opaque black before masking/blending.

Comment: patCol is a square area and maskCol is a semi transparent texture. So I need the patCol to appear only in the area of maskCol texture areas only. not in other areas of square

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/NUjimR3 , The output is currently as this. Mask Color Image is https://imgur.com/gallery/R1Av2nc . In alpha zero places white is coming. I need to remove the white areas in the alpha zero areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're not using maskCol in your return I'm going to assume you were trying to do something like:

```
    float4 patCol...
    float4 maskCol...
    return float4(patCol.rgb, maskCol.a);
```

That is, taking the alpha value from the mask and applying it to the source patCol...

For it to work you need to set the blending options in your pipelineDescriptor:

```
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

That's going to give you the "default" behavior, source-over blending: source.rgba + destination.rgba

Comment: Worked. Blending is the issue